# Cutting plane in IP system

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

I am doing branch-and-bound for 5 decision binary variables. so Decision would be 0 and 1. 
and I found sub-problem node Q with optimal value 5.4 (0.3, 0.2, 1, 0.5, 0.1)

my IP constraints  are

```
x1 + 2x2 + x3   <= 4
2x1 + 3x2 + x3  <= 3
x1 + x2 + 2x3 + x4 <= 3
```

how can I find "cutting plane" that makes Q solution infeasible ?

I need to recompute optimal solution for Q after introducing cutting plane but this is 
next step.

Should I introduce some slack variables ?

Answer (score 1):

E.g. consider the second constraint.  If $x_2 = 0$, $2 x_1 + x_3 \le 3$ is true
(with $0 \le x_1, x_3 \le 1$, but if $x_2 = 1$, you must have $x_1 = 0$ and $x_3 = 0$.
Thus $x_1 + x_2 \le 1$ and $x_2 + x_3 \le 1$ are possible cutting planes.

Comment: thanks, in same way, should I try to find first and third equation too ? I can`t make planes with hint that you gave above because I can only pick between 0 and 1.

Comment: The first constraint is useless: it's always true if all $x_i \le 1$.  The third doesn't help either: $[0.3,0.2,1,0.5] = 0.3 [1,0,1,0] + 0.2 [0,1,1,0] + 0.5 [0,0,1,1]$ is a convex combination of binary vectors $[1,0,1,0], [0,1,1,0], [0,0,1,1]$ that all satisfy it.
The only one that produces cutting planes is the second constraint, because $[0,1,1,0]$ doesn't satisfy it.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't think you can use $x_1 + x_2 \le 1$ or $x_2 + x_3 \le 1$.

Comment: I think x1 + x2 <= 1 can not "cut off" the solution , isn`t it ?

Comment: $x_1 + x_2 \le 1$ doesn't, but $x_2 + x_3 \le 1$ does.